# Extracting Values from Pandas Dataframe for Multiple Date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series as pandas dataframe, that have one column named "pre". The index of the dataframe is pandas date_range. The dates range from `1998-01-01` to `2002-12-31`.

I want to get the sum of pre values from "1998-01-01" to "1998-05-31" plus "1998-09-01" to "1998-12-31". After getting this for the year 1998, how can I get the same for all the years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
np.random.seed(2020)

r = pd.date_range('1998-01-01','2002-12-31')
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=len(r)), index=r)
# print (s)

out = {y: s.loc[f"{y}-01-01":f"{y}-05-31"].sum() + s.loc[f"{y}-09-01":f"{y}-12-31"].sum() 
       for y in range(1998, 2003)}
print (out)
{1998: 1235, 1999: 1201, 2000: 1154, 2001: 1270, 2002: 1184}
```

Another solution is convert `DatetimeIndex` to months and remove `6,7,8` months and then grouping by years with aggregate `sum`:

```
s1 = s[~s.index.month.isin([6,7,8])]
print (s1.groupby(s1.index.year).sum())
1998    1235
1999    1201
2000    1154
2001    1270
2002    1184
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Showing syntax error, invalid syntax after `f"{y}-01-01"`

Comment: @lsr729 - what is your python version? It working `3.5+`

Comment: @lsr729 - Also added new solution, it working for any pandas versions,  Ithink.